# Best Practices for SSIS Staging to Live

Tags: sql-server, ssis

SO I've been using SSIS for a while now and when I make a change in SSIS staging, I'll then open up SSIS in live and simply copy those changes.

Whats the best practice in 2019 for doing something similar but have a repository like Git? Is there software or something Git specific that people use?

I want to get away from the manual change process and have a way to have mt dtsx packages in a place with version control, looking to see what others do.

Thanks

Comment: Kind of a broad topic here. There are a few applications that help automate the dacpac (or other) deployments. Have you looked at the Schema Compare tool in VS? And the SSISDB catalog has a versioning system if you are on 2012+. Are you using package or project deployment?

Comment: I think you should check SSISDB

Comment: I think this depends alot on how you've structured your source code. Not source control, but within your solutions and packages. How do you organize your source code? Could be a project is just a collection of isolated packages that are grouped together by function (they do similar tasks) but they do not interoperate. Conversely your project could be highly integrated (packages calling and dependent on other packages, passing params back and forth, etc...) and could even be a collection of such packages in one big wrapping solution. In each case, I might have a different release strategy.